# Is filemerge still available after Xcode 4.3 installation?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, osx-lion

Where can I find `filemerge` after Xcode is upgraded to 4.3?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In Xcode, choose this menu item: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> FileMerge. The app itself is here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app
```

On the command line, use `opendiff`. You must have the command line tools installed -- go to Xcode, Preferences, Downloads tab, and install Command Line Tools if you haven't already.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: I get `Error: Can't run /Developer/usr/bin/opendiff (no such file).` Xcode 4.3 removed this folder altogether, and now `/usr/bin/opendiff` exists but gives me this error

Comment: You can also launch it from directly within xcode, on the top bar. Click "Xcode" >> "open developer tools"

Comment: If the command-line doesn't work, and you have no /Developer directory anymore, you probably need to: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Answer (score 32):

Run this in your terminal:

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but `sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` did.

Comment: Weird, it worked for me. I'll leave it unedited for now, and people will just try both methods and use the one that works for them.